# Дополнительные возможности установки apk

Tags: java, android, установка, инструменты-разработчика

1. У менять есть порядка 10 apk файлов, которые надо инсталлировать на Android устройства. Если устанавливать их по отдельности, то это занимает много времени. Есть ли способ установить все приложения разом, при помощи клика на один файл?
2. Можно ли при этом чтобы после установки на рабочем столе на приложения автоматически создались ярлыки?
3. Можно ли при этом автоматически перенести нужные мне файлы в нужное мне место?

Comment: Соберите все свои комментарии в один нормальный ответ, пожалуйста

Comment: Сделал, в начале сайт мне писал, что добавить ответ нельзя, но оказывается можно добавить комментарий и преобразовать его в ответ, после чего сделать нормальным и развернутым. По-моему это сильная не логичность и пример не дружелюбного дизайна.

Comment: а где конкретно в activity писать код, для решения 2-ой задачи?

Comment: Я писал в методе OnCreate()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Я поступил следующим образом: сделал другой apk файл, в нем для решения 1 задачи:

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile("instal.apk");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivityForResult(intent,5000);
```

Для решения 2 задачи: В AndroidManifest.xml пишем

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
```

А в Activity пишем:

```
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent();
shortcutIntent.setClassName("com.name.package", ".NameActivity");
shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
shortcutIntent.addCategory(Intent.ACTION_PICK_ACTIVITY);
Intent intentSC = new Intent();
intentSC.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
intentSC.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "NameShortcut");
intentSC.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON,
BitmapFactory.decodeFile("PathToFileIcon.png"));
intentSC.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
sendBroadcast(intentSC);
```

Для решения третьей задачи:

В AndroidManifest.xml пишем:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

В Activity пишем:

```
public void copyDirectory(File sourceLocation , File targetLocation)  
throws IOException {        
    if (sourceLocation.isDirectory()) {
        if (!targetLocation.exists()) {
            targetLocation.mkdirs();
        }

        String[] children = sourceLocation.list();
        for (int i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
            copyDirectory(new File(sourceLocation, children[i]),
                    new File(targetLocation, children[i]));
        }
    } else {

    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(sourceLocation);
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(targetLocation);

    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
}
```

И в конце, чтобы не оставлять следы на устройстве удаляем сами себя:

```
Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:com.name.apk.package");
Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI);
startActivity(uninstallIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Нет. Можно отметить несколько, к примеру, в appinstaller и установить.
2. Нет, на рабочий стол автоматом иконки не ставятся, только в список приложений.
3. Нет.